# Set window position correctly on X

Tags: c, x11

Simple question: how do I set the position of a window in X11 taking into account any window manager added decoration?

I'm aware that when I create a window the window manager will wrap it in another window so that if I want to get the "true" position of the window I have to do something like this

```
XGetGeometry(dpy, win, &root, &oldx, &oldy, &w, &h, &bw, &depth);
XTranslateCoordinates(dpy, win, root, oldx, oldy, &newx, &newy, &c);
```

How, then, do I correctly use `XMoveWindow()` to move a window so that `newx` and `newy` are what I want?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use _NET_FRAME_EXTENTS property to set the offsets.

Answer (score 1):

As it has been pointed out, you can't.  The main reason is that the XServer passes all your geometry requests to the window manager (this is why it's considered a *different* kind of client and you cannot have several window managers running at once), who decides if it grants them or not.  In case of a rigid window manager, you'll not be allowed to move a window at all.  Or it can move the window in a different way than you requested.

Comment: Well, you can, as it has also been pointed out, some properties in the client window help you in detecting the decorations the wm puts around, but this is also a facility given by wms in general and you cannot fully trust it fully.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Period. As far as I know, the window manager of your X session can add any decoration it likes, so your window can shift quite a few pixels. Or it may decide to leave your original window in place and offset its decoration accordingly.

There are some things you can try and compensate like what you did, but there's no guarantee it will work on **all** window managers.

This of course begs the question: why do you want to do this?

Comment: I want to be able to get the window position (using the code in my question), save it for later, and then restore the window position exactly as it was. I would have thought a it's a pretty common type of thing to do.

Comment: Ah... then it would make sense to store the position of the decorating window instead. You should be able to get the parent window using [XQueryTree](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window-information/XQueryTree.html).